# Copy the style of a word document into another one using Matlab

Tags: matlab, ms-word, ms-office

I need to copy the style of word document into another using Matlab.

Until now I opened my word document and a word template using actxserver:

```
wrd = actxserver('word.application');
set(wrd,'Visible',1)
wrdDoc = wrd.Documents;
wrdFile = invoke(wrdDoc,'Open','D:\myDoc.doc');
wrdFile2= invoke(wrdDoc,'Open','D:\myTemplate.dotx');
```

I would like to copy the style of the template into my document.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with automating Office from Matlab, but usually styles can be copied from a template using the [`Document.CopyStylesFromTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840260%28v=office.15%29.aspx) function.

In Matlab, this probably looks as follows:

```
invoke(wrdFile,'CopyStylesFromTemplate','D:\myTemplate.dotx');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!
Do you know if there is a way to import also the header/footer?